# Navigate to RecordView with ID parameter from APEX - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to navigate to the newly createdRecord(from apex) with the following code.

I confirmed, that the Id from apex is passed correctly.

When I "handleClick" for the first time, alert with page not found apears, if I do that again, I am correctly navigated to the record page I want. I think I made a mistake with referencing "this" value..but cant figure it out anyway. Thank you for the help

```
import { api, LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import {NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/NewAP.getData';
import createARwithPTH from '@salesforce/apex/NewAP.createAPwithPTH';


export default class NewAP extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

//nonrelated code

  handleClick(){
        var recId ="";
        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        console.log('1',el);
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        console.log('2',selected);
        createARwithPTH({selectedRows: selected})
            .then(result=>{this.recId=result})
            console.log('3',this.recId);
        this.navigateToRecordViewPage(this.recId);
    }
    navigateToRecordViewPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recId,
                objectApiName: 'Acceptance_Protocol__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please add the class declaration, the navigateMixin needs to extend extends NavigationMixin, so could you add it on your question, so then we can discard this possibility

Comment: Done, its there, as I said, it is working, but always on the socond try :D

Comment: on the first time, what is the ID on the URL?

Comment: there is non.In the first run console.log('3',this.recId) is undefined in the2 nd run its defined with the valid id and correctly redirected. It looks like during the first run, id is not initialized, only when I run it on the second run, I can get the value and also see it in the log. createARwithPTH(Apex) creates new object and returns its Id

Comment: oh right, sorry I just realize it,
what is happening is because the way JavaScript works, I'll write the answer

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is because the createARwithPTH is async work, JavaScript works with Promises to handle this type of work, as we know JavaScript is a single Thread, but this is not the scope of the question.

you have two ways to solve this:
The first way, add the navigation call to the promise resolve

```js
  handleClick(){
        var recId ="";
        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        console.log('1',el);
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        console.log('2',selected);
        createARwithPTH({selectedRows: selected})
            .then( (result) => {
                this.recId=result;
                console.log('3',this.recId);
                this.navigateToRecordViewPage();
         })
    }
    navigateToRecordViewPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recId,
                objectApiName: 'Acceptance_Protocol__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
            
        });
    }
```

The second way is to await for the promise result:

```js
  async handleClick(){
        var recId ="";
        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        console.log('1',el);
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        console.log('2',selected);
        await createARwithPTH({selectedRows: selected})
            .then( (result) => {
                this.recId=result;
         })
        console.log('3',this.recId);
                this.navigateToRecordViewPage();
    }
    navigateToRecordViewPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recId,
                objectApiName: 'Acceptance_Protocol__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
            
        });
    }
```